# Select largest square chunk for data from numpy array with no data values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, subset

I need to select the square section of data within an 2D numpy array with nan's as the no data value. Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np


#Fake Data
data =np.reshape(np.arange(100,dtype='float64'), (10,10))
extra_cols = np.zeros((1,10), dtype=data.dtype)
data = np.concatenate((data,extra_cols),axis=0)
data = np.concatenate((extra_cols,data),axis=0)
extra_rows = np.zeros((12,1), dtype=data.dtype)
data = np.concatenate((data,extra_rows),axis=1)
data = np.concatenate((extra_rows,data),axis=1)
data[data==0] = np.nan


#Target data
target =np.reshape(np.arange(100,dtype='float64'), (10,10))
target[target==0] = np.nan

target= targettarget[1:,1:]
```

Basically, I am trying to find an efficient way to extract `target` from `data`.    In my example `data` represents an input image with no data regions surrounding the images data and `target` is a subset of `data`.

In non-technical terms, I need to select the largest square blob of data from an irregularly shaped blob of data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure I cracked it.  A couple of days and too much coffee.

```
import numpy as np

def crop_to_data(mask, im):
    true_points = np.argwhere(mask)
    top_left = true_points.min(axis=0)
    # take the largest points and use them as the bottom right of your crop
    bottom_right = true_points.max(axis=0)
    cmask = mask[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]+1, top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]+1]
    cim = im[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]+1, top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]+1]

    #convert to boolian array
    cmask = cmask.astype(bool)
    nrows, ncols = np.shape(cmask)

    maxarea = (0, [])

    arr = np.asarray(cmask, dtype='int')
    wid = np.zeros(dtype=int, shape=arr.shape)
    hght = np.zeros(dtype=int, shape=arr.shape)

    for row in xrange(nrows):
        for col in xrange(ncols):
            if arr[row][col] == 0:
                continue

            if row == 0:
                hght[row][col] = 0
            else:
                hght[row][col] = hght[row-1][col]+1

            if col == 0:
                wid[row][col] = 0
            else:
                wid[row][col] = wid[row][col-1]+1
            min_w = wid[row][col]

            for delta_hght in xrange(hght[row][col]):
                min_w = np.min([min_w, wid[row-delta_hght][col]])
                areanow = (delta_hght+1)*min_w
                if areanow > maxarea[0]:
                    maxarea = (areanow, [(row-delta_hght, col-min_w+1, row, col)])

    t = np.squeeze(maxarea[1])

    min_row = t[0]; max_row = t[2]
    min_col = t[1]; max_col = t[3]

    cim = cim[min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col]

    return cmask,cim 

#Fake Data
data =np.reshape(np.arange(100,dtype='float64'), (10,10))
extra_cols = np.zeros((1,10), dtype=data.dtype)
data = np.concatenate((data,extra_cols),axis=0)
data = np.concatenate((extra_cols,data),axis=0)
extra_rows = np.zeros((12,1), dtype=data.dtype)
data = np.concatenate((data,extra_rows),axis=1)
data = np.concatenate((extra_rows,data),axis=1)


mask = np.zeros(data.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
mask[data > 0] = 255

cmask, target = crop_to_data(mask,data)
```

Produces `target`:

```
[[11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0],
 [21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0],
 [31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0],
 [41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0],
 [51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0],
 [61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0],
 [71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0],
 [81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0]]
```